# I followed rsync instruction to create a repo - can't update X packages from it

Tags: repository

I ran this command to create my local repo:

```
rsync -av rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/ /ubuntu/ubuntu-mirror/pool/
```

I've set my sources.list file to look at it:

```
deb [trusted=yes]  http://ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic main restricted
deb [trusted=yes]  http://ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
deb [trusted=yes]  http://ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic universe
deb [trusted=yes]  http://ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-updates universe
deb [trusted=yes]  http://ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb [trusted=yes]  http://ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse
deb [trusted=yes]  http://ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

I've run the apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, packages update just fine.
However, if I try something like `apt-get install gdm3` I end up in dependency hell. I get messages like

```
gdm3: Depdends: gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92) but it is not going to be installed
```

walking the dependency tree reveals more of the same. As it turns out, I have gnome_shell starting at 3.26.1, but nothing as old as the install dvd.

I installed from the 18.04.1 LTS server. Question is, how do I get an ubuntu local repo that has the right stuff so I can install these packages?

Comment: So I found some new info - perhaps my universe repository isn't enabled. There's a command, but I have to install software-properties-common to get add-apt-repository... guess what, dependencies like above prevent me from doing this. It tries to download unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.18.04.7_all.deb which doesn't exist. 18.04.8 does, and so does unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.18.04.7~16.04.1_all.deb.

Answer (score 0):

I resynced it with:

```
 rsync --recursive --links --perms --times --compress --progress --delete rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu /ubuntu/ubuntu-mirror2/
```

So far, this is working. Perhaps some symlinks or timestamps were not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a copy of pool only, but you also need to include dists folder in order to make it work properly, so you need to change you command to include dist like this
rsync -av rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ /ubuntu/ubuntu-mirror/